# How does Black Bolt eat?

Tags: marvel, inhumans

If the Inhuman, Black Bolt, can't open his mouth without causing untold destruction, why hasn't he starved to death a long time ago?

Comment: Surely it's his *voice* that causes the destruction, not merely opening his mouth; [something something speech centre](https://static1.cbrimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/black-bolt-official-handbook-marvel-universe.jpg)

Comment: Silently.‮‮‮‮‮‮‮‬‬‬‬‬‬‬‎‮‮‮‮‮‬‬‬‬‬‎

Comment: not very well... but that is due to his dental problems...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's Black Bolt's *voice*, specifically, which is destructive, not merely the act of him opening his mouth.

> An organic mechanism in his brain's speech center produces an unknown particle that interacts with ambient electrons, enabling him to produce certain mentally-controlled phenomena. But, the most devastating of the effects is Black Bolt's quasi-sonic scream. Because his electron-harnessing ability is linked to the speech center of his brain, **any attempt to use his vocal cords triggers an uncontrollable disturbance of the particle/electron interaction field. At full strength, his voice generates a shockwave equivalent to a nuclear weapon's, while a whisper can rock a battleship.** The fork-like antenna worn upon his forehead helps Black Bolt control his powers.
>
> <sub>https://www.marvel.com/characters/black-bolt/in-comics</sub>

> DOCTOR STRANGE: Black Bolt does not bother to bloody his knuckles in this fight. He doesn't have to. **His power isn't of muscle and bone. It's in his voice--each syllable a concussive blast of physical force.**
>
> [image: Doctor Strange Vol. 5 #16, page 11]
>
> <sub>*[Doctor Strange Vol. 5 #16](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange_Vol_5_16)* (September, 2019)</sub>

Comment: ```Sound does not travel in space. The vacuum of outer space has essentially zero air. Because sound is just vibrating air, space has no air to vibrate and therefore no sound.```

Comment: "fork-like"? There is actually no proper English word for this fork-like tuning tool?

Comment: @stef, I'm pretty sure it's just called a "tuning fork"

Comment: quasi-sonic scream?

Comment: Which lead to one of the best ever Marvel quotes, when Hulk went after him.  "I don't want to hear you whisper.  I want to hear you scream."